# Get average of columns in pandas based on particular rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have a data that stores % change in value for stocks over one day, month, three months and year.

```
ID     daychange   monthchange   trimonthchange  yearchange
UNITY   0.001666     0.398450        0.411581    0.689139
SSOM  -0.033359     0.040816        1.174840    3.047619
PNSC  -0.004953    -0.053006        0.158677    0.224932
PICT  -0.002027    -0.069696        0.041143    0.310791
PIBTL  -0.014848     0.129362        0.459846    0.287100
```

I want to get:

1. averages for each of the 4 time periods based on the ID name. For instance "UNITY" "SSOM" "PNSC" are to be grouped and their average be calculated for each time period (i.e. avg daychange for the group, avg monthchange for the group and so on).
2. that average data to be put in a separate csv file with a new single row (instead of "UNITY" "SSOM" "PNSC") and the average of each time periods for the group.

I have tried `df.mean(axis = 1)` but that doesn't do the job.

Any help will be dearly appreciated! THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) to access a group of rows by label (`ID` column) and then calculate the mean for each time period column using `axis=0`. Create a `Series` with the group's name and append the previous results to it (this way the group name will be the first column in the `dataframe`). Place the `Series` in a list, then when the iteration over the groups is done, convert to a `dataframe`. To put the resulst in a separate csv file use [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv).

```
import pandas as pd

GROUPS = [
    ["UNITY", "SSOM", "PNSC"],
    ["SSOM", "PICT", "PIBTL"],
    ["SSOM", "PNSC", "PIBTL"],
]

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep="\s+")
df = df.set_index("ID")

data = []
for g in GROUPS:
    group_mean = df.loc[g].mean(axis=0)
    serie = pd.Series({"groupName":"-".join(g)}).append(group_mean)
    data.append(serie)

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)
data.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Output from **data**

```
         groupName  daychange  monthchange  trimonthchange  yearchange
0  UNITY-SSOM-PNSC  -0.012215     0.128753        0.581699    1.320563
1  SSOM-PICT-PIBTL  -0.016745     0.033494        0.558610    1.215170
2  SSOM-PNSC-PIBTL  -0.017720     0.039057        0.597788    1.186550
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any idea why would it give raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['ID'] are in the columns"

Comment: I have copied the dataframe you posted in your question to a `sample.csv`, that's why I am using the `sep='\s+'`. If your CSV file has the default separator (`,`) you can remove the `sep` parameter and should work. Also, you can always `print(df.head())` to make sure the dataframe has the expected structure.

Comment: Thank you loads!! It works. Lastly, for my curiosity can u suggest something if I want to change the group name to some more concise and custom.

Comment: It is a challenge to give relevant suggestions with limited context, but a direct improvement would be to change from `list of lists` to `dictionary` with lists (e.g `groupDict ={'G1': ['UNITY', 'SSOM', 'PNSC'], 'G2': ['SSOM', 'PICT', 'PIBTL']}`) using the `key` as group name.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to chain both the `filter` and `mean` function calls. Since you first want to select a set of rows to keep, you need to filter out the ones that you don't. Then, with the new dataset, you want to execute your column averaging.

```py
df.filter(lambda row: row.ID in ["UNITY", "SSOM", "PNSC"]).mean(axis = 1)
```

*Note, I have not tested the above code, and make no guarantees that it will work as-is*

Comment: It doesn't :/  return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable